# Need correction in cts:and-query-options documentation

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

Please see the attached image with this question. If you see the documentation of [cts:and-query-options](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:and-query-options), everything is fine except the example.

In the example, it is returning `cts:and-query-queries` instead of `cts:and-query-options`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the example query for [`cts:and-query-options()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:and-query-options) is incorrect, using `cts:and-query-queries()` instead.

```
let $query :=
  cts:and-query((
    cts:word-query("to be or"),
    cts:word-query("or not to be")))
return cts:and-query-queries($query)
=> ()
```

should be:

```
let $query :=
cts:and-query((
  cts:word-query("to be or"),
  cts:word-query("or not to be")
))
return cts:and-query-options($query)
=> ()
```

A documentation bug has been filed in order to get that corrected.